# Is there a possibility to have an inferior good (x) in a utility function where x & y have 0 cross elasticity?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, elasticity

A question I got on an exam that I think I messed up on:
If we have cross elasticity of 0 (x & y are independent), can x be an inferior good? I answered with a yes. Am I wrong?

Comment: The interesting thing would be to tell us _why_ you answered yes, or at least why now you think that you should have answered no.

Comment: Why I answered yes: ran out of time, why I think I'm wrong: I can't think of such a function

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos do you have an answer at least? :/

Comment: Possibly, but not yet.